# How do I get the response returned from Rack in a Cucumber step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, rack

I have a Cucumber step for my Rails application:

```
Then /^I should be redirected to the sign in page$/ do
  assert_equal 302, @response.status
end
```

But that `@response` object is the one returned by my `Controller`, and it's the Rack middleware that sets the status to what I expect it to be.  How can I get at the response as returned from the outer-most middleware instead of the one returned from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

From your step definition it sounds like you should be testing whether you're on the sign in page, not whether you got a 302.  But to go your way, here's the step:

```
Then /^I should be redirected to the sign in page$/ do |url|
  assert @integration_session.status == 302, "Expected status to be 302, got #{@integration_session.status}"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using just `response` without the '@'. It will give you the response object WebRat sees.